# How to Revert Storybook AddOns Panel to Bottom?

Tags: storybook

My Storybook Addons panel is displaying on the RHS of the page, but I want it at the bottom. How do I do this?

I hit some keyboard shortcut and inadvertently changed the panel to display on the right hand side, whereas it was at the bottom beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated Answer

Turns out the key was just "d". This toggled the panel from the RHS to the bottom.

Without focusing on inside any inputs or text areas, but while the focus is inside the Story, just hit "d" to toggle between the AddOns on the RHS and the bottom.

Seems like others have had difficulty with default shortcuts in Storybook. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16022).

#### Original Answer

I have a solution that's a hack. I thought I'd post this solution as I couldn't find an easy way to do it by Googling, and others may be stuck in a similar way. This solution works for Google Chrome but I'm sure it can be adapted:

1. Open DEV tools in Chrome (ctrl+shift+J)
2. Go to the Application tab
3. Clear the entry called `@storybook/ui/store` from session storage, if it exists
4. In local storage, find the entry `@storybook/ui/store` and choose to edit its value. You'll see it's a JSON string representing an object.
5. Change `panelPosition: "right"` to `panelPosition: "bottom"`
6. Refresh Storybook

Officially, according to [this page](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/features-and-behavior):

> To control the layout of Storybook’s UI you can use addons.setConfig
> in your .storybook/manager.js:

However, I wasn't using a `manager.js` file so wasn't sure how this applied to me.